# number of vertices in a self-complemntary graph

Tags: graph-theory

Problem: Prove that the number of vertices of a self-complementary graph must be congruent to 0 or 1 modulo 4.
I think my starting point would be that P4 and C5 are self-complementary and proceed by induction by adding P4s.
I established the first step in a previous problem, but I need help on the induction step.
i.e. proving that adjoining P4 will indeed yield a self-complementary graph.

Comment: Induction will likely not work as a proof method. It's unclear why any subgraph will still be self-complementary.

Comment: What do you mean a number must be 'congruent to 0 or modulo 1'? In  what sense congruent to $0$, and in what sense modulo $1$?

Comment: [Linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788190/proof-that-any-self-complementary-graph-has-to-have-4k-or-4k1-vertex-for-s?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** If a graph with $n$ vertices is self-complementary, then the complete graph on $n$ vertices has an even number of edges.

Hence $n \equiv 0, 1 \pmod{4} $.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Forget about induction. Consider an isomorphism between the graph and its complement as a permutation of the vertex set. Show that the length of a cycle (in the disjoint-cycle representation of that permutation) can only be $1$ (a fixed point) or a multiple of $4$, and that you can't have more than one fixed point.

Comment: Can you give me a hint to prove the two?
I thought about it for a while, but I'm stuck.

Comment: I know about permutations and disjoint cycle form. I said two because I considered (1) and (2) as one. 
I need help on all three.

Comment: (3)Now I do.
If two points are fixed, for example (1)(2)(345), the edge 12 is exists in both graphs.
Otherwise, vertices 1 and 2 are isolated points, which cannot happen in a self-complementary graph.

Comment: @user14111 I misread, in part without your edit which clarified what you meant.