# Proof that any self-complementary graph has to have $4k$ or $4k+1$ vertex, for some $k \in \mathbb N$

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

I've seen looking on previous questions that using [this](http://math.nie.edu.sg/fmdong/In-service/self-com.pdf) algorithm, I can construct self-complementary graphs.

I got confused at this point, because I'm not sure if I should proof that there are no graphs with $4k+2 $ or $4k+3$ vertex, in witch case the algorithm doesn't seem to be very helpful.

Is this enough to proof that the graph has to have $4k$ or $4k+1$ vertex?

Comment: What do you want to show ?  That the algorithm can generate EVERY self-complementary graph ?  If so, then you have to show that as well.  But if all you want to show is that there are no such graphs with $4k + 2$ or $4k + 3$ vertices, then that's enough.

Comment: I what to show the that there are no such graphs with $4k+2$ or $4k+3$ vertices, then that's enough.

Comment: Then it's enough to prove that such graphs must have $4k$ or $4k + 1$ vertices.  Does that answer the question or were you also looking for a proof ?

Comment: A proof would be nice

Comment: There it is :)   Though I'm still wondering if the proposed algorithm can construct every possible self-complementary graph, if we start with $P_4$, $C_5$ and the bull.  I wouldn't think so but who knows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a classic result and it's even on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-complementary_graph).

If $G$ is self-complementary, then its edges contain half of all of the possible edges (and the complement has the others).  Thus if $G$ has $n$ vertices, its number of edges is

$$
\frac{{n \choose 2}}{2} = \frac{n(n - 1)}{4}
$$

Thus $n$ or $n - 1$ must be a multiple of $4$ (I'm pretty sure you can figure that out if needed).  That is, $n = 4k$ or $n = 4k + 1$ for some $k$.